# I must install django for every single project i make?

Tags: python, django, web

i am new to Python programming language and Django. I am learning about web development with Django, however, each time I create a new project in PyCharm, it doesn´t recognize django module, so i have to install it again. Is this normal? Because i´ve installed django like 5 times. It doesn´t seem correct to me, there must be a way to install Django once and for all and not have the necessity of using 'pip install django' for each new project I create, I am sure there must be a way but I totally ignore it, I think I have to add django to path but I really don´t know how (just guessing). I will be thankful if anyone can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pycharm runs in a venv. A venv is an isolated duplicate (sort of) of python (interpreter) and other scripts. To use your main interpreter, change your interpreter location. The three folders (where your projects is, along with your other files) are just that. I think there is an option to inherit packages. I like to create a file called `requirements.txt` and put all my modules there. Comment for further help.

In conclusion, this is normal.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of starting your project in PyCharm.

1. To use a virtual environment where you have to install the external libraries into this environment.
2. To start using the existing interpreter. (If you chose this option you don't have to install it again installing it only once globally would be enough)

So when you start to create a new project choose the existing interpreter.

[image]

Doing this will not require you to install it every time(But is not recommended for big projects as there would dependencies on different versions of libraries).